# Tensorboard: Why is there a zigzag pattern at gradient plots?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Here is a picture of the gradient of a conv2d layer (the kernel). It has a zigsag pattern which I would like to understand. What I understand is that the gradient changes from mini-batch to mini-batch. But why does it increase after each epoch?

I am using the Keras Adam optimizer with default settings. I dont think that is the reason. Dropout and Batch-Norm. should also not be the reason. I am using image augmentation but that does not change its behavior from batch to batch.

Does anybody have an idear?

[image: Gradient of conv2d layer]

Comment: This question is very hard to be answered. On what data? How are you exactly fitting it? Please provide a complete minimal verifiable example...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with keras metrics.

In that case the problem was that the metrics maintain a running average across each epoch, and it's that "average so far" that they report to TensorBoard.

How are these grads getting to TensorBoard? Are you passing them to a [tf.keras.metrics.Mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Mean)? If so you probably want to call "reset_states" on it. Maybe in an [custom callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback)'s `on_batch_end`.

Comment: I am using the keras tensorboard callback: `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`